# How to delete a webresponse based on jsessionId in c#?

Tags: java, c#, cookies, jsessionid

I am trying to do API testing in c#. I have a webresponse with some values uploaded to a url and a WebClient object with some headers (JSESSIONID, path etc)

```
    string cookie = JSESSIONID : ajyrnXWREThsarfoWSGGREGarevr;
    myWebClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie);
    var responseArray1 = myWebClient.UploadValues(restURL, "POST", myQueryStringCollection2);
```

Now I want to delete the response with the above JSESSIONID.

I was able to do this in Java with the below code:

```
    Client client = Client.create();
    Builder webResource = client.resource(restUrl).cookie(cookie);
    ClientResponse response1 = webResource.type("application/json").delete(ClientResponse.class);
```

Please let me know how to proceed in C#.

Comment: What you had tried so far ?

Comment: I tried remove method.
responseHeaders.Headers and then looping it to remove each header. But I want to delete the cookies.

Comment: I don't know Java but this didn't helped you ?? 'cookie.setMaxAge(0);' ?